# Am I getting Scheme wrong?

Tags: functional-programming, scheme

Inspired by the numerous posts about the importance of learning Lisp/Scheme I started to learn Scheme two days back, I am using the book "The little Schemer" and have completed half of it.

But I still haven't learned anything new, the book teaches about recursion which I already understand and uses lambda (which I can think of a way to define a function in C). I still haven't got the concept of functional programming (please point to some example of functional compared to normal programming methods in C/C++ so I can get it).

Am I learning in the wrong way? or is "The little Schemer" for a newbie in programming and I should look for some other books?

Comment: Get a copy of the book suggested by SK-logic, and *make yourself through the exercises*!

Comment: so are you actually writing scheme i.e. doing exercise while reading this book, or have you just read it without writing code?

Comment: @jk. I write sometimes, not always

Comment: ...I actually liked that book. Nevertheless, nothing is better than hands on practice afterwards!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Wait until you'll get to the lexical closures.

Than try to grasp the homoiconic property of the language - this is what makes it really different from the C-likes.

And make sure you'll learn a Scheme with a proper `define-macro` implementation (I'd recommend Racket or Bigloo), not just standard hygienic macros (the latter would not surprise you at all if you're familiar with the C++ templates). Most Scheme textbooks would skip this stuff, unfortunately, but I'd argue that there is nothing nearly as important in Lisps as the proper macros.

It is also important to try to understand the purely functional subset of Scheme and learn how to solve all the possible programming problems with it. "Little Schemer" is a good starting point, but not nearly sufficient. Go through ["Structure and Interpretation of Computer programs"](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/) after it.

Comment: -1 for suggesting `define-macro`.  There is no reason to ever use this thing other than the possibility of learning why it is wrong.

Comment: @EliBarzilay, ok, I see, you're not advocating the stupid hygiene, it is all about separating runtime and compile time. Then you're even more wrong. There is one really generic way: incremental compilation, as in Common Lisp. You can build any kind of macro system on top of this generic approach, including that staged Racket system. But the opposite is not true (and all the claims that this macro system is equally expressive are just lies).

Comment: I agree with Eli---`define-macro` has no place in modern Scheme programming. You can write fully procedural macros using `syntax-case` or explicit renaming without having to stoop to unhygienic macros.

Comment: P.S. Implementing `define-macro` on top of `syntax-case` is extremely trivial---Guile does exactly this, for compatibility with legacy code still using the former---but the reverse is much, much, much harder. So, which macro system is more expressive, again? :-)

Comment: +1 for SICP. The lectures are also [available as videos](http://groups.csail.mit.edu/mac/classes/6.001/abelson-sussman-lectures/) for those not so much into reading.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young, if you're up to something called "modern Scheme programming", then, probably, you're right. If you want to learn the Zen of Lisp, you *have* to grasp the most fundamental, the most basic, the simplest and the most generic approach to code transformations, namely, Common Lisp-style macros. Is it clear? And, no, you're wrong: `syntax-case` is more complex, and therefore, less fundamental and less expressive. I've actually implemented `syntax-case` on top of the most basic `defmacro` in about 300 lines of code. Piece of cake.

Comment: From now on, I will be using the first two sentences out of this very answer to trick people into technobabble traps: +1

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young: Much more than just "harder" -- I don't know of anyone who showed that it is possible to implement hygiene on top of `define-macro`, and the common opinion is that it is impossible without redefining other parts of the language.

Comment: @SK-logic: I somehow doubt that you implemented `syntax-case` with `define-macro`.  It's something that many people have tried and failed.  The most serious attempt that I know about is Pascal Costanza's paper, and that requires redefining `lambda` and a bunch of other core language forms.  (IOW, it is not a working solution for CL, because you're not allowed to redefine core forms.)

Comment: @SK-logic: and the same goes for phase separation & incremental compilation -- without a way to enforce that, you just can't do it in the language.  See for example [xcvb](http://common-lisp.net/project/xcvb/) where Fare's solution is to run a separate process for each file compilation -- the only way that could enforce deterministic compilation without an enforced phase separation in the language.

Comment: @EliBarzilay, with define-macro you can rebuild the whole language from scratch, so it is not a problem at all. You do not have to "re-define" a language, just implement a lightweight frontend compiler with its own macro expansion mechanism. Same for the phase separation. Having a generic, unrestricted defmacro allows you to change the behaviour of your compiler any way you like.

Comment: @SK-logic: You're mixing things up.  The issue is *expressiveness*.  You can (easily) implement `define-macro` using `define-syntax` -- where the implementation is a macro.  If you're dealing with a frontend for the language, then you're not using the macro system (and you can do so in any language, since you don't need macros).  So your argument falls into the old Turing Machine bin, where any TM-equivalent language can do the same.  (Even with that, a hygienic macro expander in 300 lines would be impressive.  You should publicize such a miracle.)

Comment: @EliBarzilay, ok, let's start from a different end: you're building a Lisp compiler from scratch. You're growing this language gradually, from the very simple and basic forms to the more powerful and capable. What kind of macro system would you introduce first? A trivial defmacro, which you'll use for growing the rest of your system until you can painlessly build a more advanced expander, or you'll waste a lot of effort on implementing an overcomplicated but "nice" and "clean" phase-separated hygienic system (btw., I see no point at all in hygiene, but it is a different story).

Comment: Assuming that the goal is to have a hygienic macro system, there is no answer to your question, since both ways would require the same kind of work.

Comment: @EliBarzilay, no, you're wrong again. If you start with implementing a hygienic system (what for?!? it is pointless...), with a primitive language, you'll waste a lot of time and effort, whereas if you start building up your language expressiveness with defmacro first, later on you'll need those 300 lines only to add hygiene and the other useless stuff.

Comment: See your earlier comment about implementing a hygienic system as a front-end: this means that it is no longer related to macros, only the ability to run any code at the meta level, which is why your question asks about an irrelevant decision.  Macros *do* help when there is a *local* transformation rule that you want to implement, and implementing a hygienic macros is not known to be possible with local rules (again, see Costanza's attempt).

Comment: As for your side-comments about hygiene being pointless: this is not some opinion that you'd change here, and apparently people who do use Scheme value it.  Given this, and given that you have no concrete evidence against it, and given that it contributes nothing, I suggest you just drop it.  (And before you start flaming, just think whether there's any point to such flaming.)

Answer (score 3):

The best way to get the taste of functional programming is to write programs.

For example, write a simple XML parser in C++ and scheme. (and do not use mutable variables in scheme).

Or solve some euler-project problems in scheme/haskell/ocaml/whatever.

Answer (score 3):

"The Little Schemer" is an exercise book, aimed at giving you a grounding in the Scheme dialect of LISP.

It is most emphatically NOT a textbook on LISP or Scheme programming, much less a text on functional programming.  For that, you want, as SK-Logic said, [Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/).